# find inner width/height of BorderContainer component

Tags: apache-flex

I have a BorderContainer having top:30, bottom:5, left:2, right:2 so that it resizes with the applicaiton.

I have a custom component within it that needs to resize when the container resizes.

The problem is that getting the width and height of the container directly is not working.  It seems to have a minimum width and height of 500.

Instead I have to get the width/height of its parent, which is in fact a BorderContainerSkin, then subtract the borderWeight * 2.

Is there a function that returns this?

Answer (score 0):

So are you trying to manage component size inside component? It's not the Flex way. The component's parent should set its children sizes during layout. Try to set percentHeight and percentWidth (or width/height="100%") in your component.